# Кличний відмінок для жіночого імені «Пайпер Фарадей»?

Tags: власні-назви, відмінювання, іноземні-імена, кличний-відмінок, іншомовні-слова

Персонажа комп’ютерної гри звуть Пайпер Фарадей. Вона жінка. Як правильно буде до неї звернутися? «Вітаю, Пайпере»?

А за прізвищем? «Вітаю, Фарадеє»?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 2013

Звуки букв **р** та **й** є [приголосними](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8), отже слова належать до [3 відміни:](http://pravopys.net/sections/44/)

> <sup>*Український правопис ¬ § 44. Поділ на відміни*</sup>
>   іменники жін. роду з кінцевим приголосним основи

Але таке [імʼя](http://pravopys.net/sections/100/) й [прізвище](http://pravopys.net/sections/102/) змінювати не можна:

> <sup>*Український правопис ¬ § 100. Відмінювання іменників іншомовного походження*</sup>
>   жіночі імена іншомовного походження на приголосний не відмінюються: *А́ліс*, *Доло́рес*, *Зейна́б*.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>*Український правопис ¬ § 102. Відмінювання прізвищ*</sup>
>   жіночі прізвища на приголосний та **о** не відмінюються: *Марі́ї Се́ник*, *Наді́ї Балі́й*, *з Ні́ною Ба́йко*.

Вітаю, **Пайпер Фарадей**!

## 2019

Змін нема, але, про всяк, варто внести декотрі [дотичні зміни](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=132) і зазначити, же **р** є негубним твердим:

> <sup>*Український правопис ¬ § 145. Несловʼянські прізвища та імена*</sup>
>   Про правопис несловʼянських прізвищ та імен див. III розділ
>   «Правопис слів іншомовного походження» (§ 121—140).
>
> ---
>
> <sup>*Український правопис ¬ § 140* [ ⋯ ]</sup>
>   Деякі іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюємо, а саме:
>
> - жіночі особові імена, що закінчуються на **-й** і на твердий приголосний (крім губних): *Беатрі́с*, *Доло́рес*, *Гюльчата́й*, *Елма́с*, *Енн*, *Жанне́т*, *Іре́н*, *Ка́рме́н*, *Кім*, *Клоді́н*, *Лено́р*, *Ма́ргарет*, *Мерсе́дес*, *Моні́к*, *Тріш*, *Фара́х* i т. ін.

Comment: Мені здається, що ці слова все-таки не належать до третьої відміни. Мені здається, що невідмінювані слова поза відмінами. Я б змінив «отже належать до 3 відміни» на «отже якби ці слова відмінювалися, то вони належали б до третьої відміни». Але ніяких доказів не маю, лише припускаю (що слова, що належать до N-ї відміни, мають відмінюються відповідно як слова цієї відміни чи хоча б *в більшості форм* як слова N-ї відміни). Але висновок, звісно, незгоди не викликає.

Comment: Наприклад, [ось](http://shkolyar.in.ua/pravopys-imennykiv/pravopys-inozemnyh): «Незмінювані іменники не належать до жодної відміни».

Comment: [Непрямо натякається, що існують іменники поза відмінами](http://subject.com.ua/textbook/mova/6klas_3/23.html): «226. Прочитайте. Визначте іменники, що не належать до жодної з відмін. З’ясуйте відміни інших іменників».

Comment: А [тут](//school-zno.com.ua/ukr-mova/morfologija/imennyk.html) прямо: «До відмін не належать: 
1) Незмінні іменники іншомовного походження: кенгуру, таксі, леді, фрау;
2) Множинні іменники: канікули, штани, Карпати;
3) Слова-абревіатури: НЛО, ЗНО.
4) Жіночі прізвища на приголосний та -о: Козак Ольга, Карпенко Соломія».

Comment: Просто мені ще в школі пояснювали, що незмінювані іменники не належать до відмін. Мені це окремо пояснювали, бо в мене було неправильне уявлення про них (в голові перемішалися уроки російської, української і власна дурість — і я раз у раз відповідав, що незмінювані іменники належать до IV відміни). Добре, як вважаєте за краще.

Comment: Ще я б змінив «3 відміни» на «3-ї відміни» або «III відміни» — але то як Вам зручніше.

Comment: P.S.: Караман, Караман і Плющ «Сучасна українська літературна мова» і Дудик та Горпинич «Українська мова» пишуть те саме.

Comment: Чисто теоретично, тут обмега лише на імя, тому можливе _Фарадеє_, але я поки уточнюю.