# Кличний відмінок слова "хетей"

Tags: відмінювання

У комп'ютерній грі до жіночого персонажа звертаються як "хетей" (слово з бурятської мови, що означає "старша сестра"). Так як це слово використовується у звертанні, то чи буде здійснюватися відмінювання цього слова. Якщо так, то як звучатиме кличний відмінок слово "хетей"?

Comment: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1493/585

Comment: Це питання є дублікатом, вказаного вище. Голосую закрити.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Кличний відмінок для жіночого імені «Пайпер Фарадей»?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b6%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%96%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%96-%d0%9f%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%a4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Фрагмент з § 140 правопису](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=132):

> Деякі іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюємо, а саме: <…>
>
> - жіночі особові імена, що закінчуються на **-й** і на твердий приголосний (крім губних): *Беатрі́с, Доло́рес, Гюльчата́й, Елма́с, Енн, Жанне́т, Іре́н, Ка́рме́н, Кім, Клоді́н, Лено́р, Ма́ргарет, Мерсе́дес, Моні́к, Тріш, Фара́х* і т. ін.

Отже *Хетей* (як жіноче ім'я) не відмінюється: «я не бачу прекрасної Хетей», «іди-но сюди, Хетей».

Upd.: Якщо це не ім'я, а загальна назва, то теж не відмінюємо. Мабуть, можна пояснити тим, що такі слова (жіночого роду на *-й*) не підпадають під ознаки жодної з відмін. (Також сказано, що не відмінюються «етикетні означення жінки, що закінчуються на приголосний: *міс, місис, мада́м, мадемуазе́ль, фре́кен, фро́йляйн, хану́м*», але не певен, що це етикетне означення.)